# Should I use a metaclass, class decorator, or override the __new__ method?

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

Here is my problem.  I want the following class to have a bunch of property attributes.  I could either write them all out like `foo` and `bar`, or based on some other examples I've seen, it looks like I could use a class decorator, a metaclass, or override the `__new__` method to set the properties automagically.  I'm just not sure what the "right" way to do it would be.

```
class Test(object):
    def calculate_attr(self, attr):
        # do calculaty stuff
        return attr

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.calculate_attr('foo')

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self.calculate_attr('bar')
```

Comment: When in doubt, always go with simple and obvious.  If *you* can't easily figure out it, neither can dummies (like me) who will be asked to maintain your code.

Comment: When you change the nature of your questions, it's usually best just to open a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magic is bad. It makes your code harder to understand and maintain. You virtually never need metaclasses or `__new__`.

It looks like your use case could be implemented with pretty straightforward code (with only a small hint of magic):

```
class Test(object):
    def calculate_attr(self, attr):
        return something

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.calculate_attr(name)
```

Comment: @You virtually never need metaclasses or `__new__`: I strongly disagree. At my company we had already two occasions, when we had good motivation for using metaclasses. First was creating abstraction layer for a custom database we had used and the other was creating our own Model system for ldap. I can't really understand, where comes this resentment for metaclasses from. It's an easy concept to grasp and really useful in certain situations.

Comment: @gruszczy, metaclasses are not difficult to understand, they're actually a pretty easy idea, though the syntax and usage for them in Python makes some people have trouble. They are, however, error-prone due to the way they propagate and sometimes difficult to combine—it is not automatically possible to have a class use two metaclasses in its construction even if that is a perfectly reasonable operation. This problem is exacerbated by the fact metaclasses are often not exposed as part of a system's public API.

Answer (score 3):

A metaclass's `__new__` does not become the `__new__` for the class you make—it's used to make the class itself. The *actual class object* is returned by the metaclass. A new instance of a class is returned by `__new__`.

Consider the following (insane) code:

```
def MyMetaClass(name, bases, dict):
    print "name", name
    print "bases", bases
    print "dict", dict
    return 7

class C('hello', 'world'):
    __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass

    foo = "bar"

    def baz(self, qux):
        pass

print "C", C
```

(I used a function instead of a class as the metaclass. Any callable can be used as a metaclass, but many people choose to right theirs as classes that inherit from `type` with new overrided. The differences between that an a function are subtle.)

It outputs

```
name C
bases ('hello', 'world')
dict {'baz': <function baz at 0x4034c844>, '__module__': '__main__', 'foo': 'bar', '__metaclass__': <function MyMetaClass at 0x40345c34>}
C 7
```

Does that help you better make sense of what metaclasses *are*?

You will **very seldom** need to define a metaclass of your own.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "actual class object" rather than "actually class object"?

Comment: i really like that the "class" C is now "7" ... intuitive

Answer (score 1):

Metaclass is used when new class - not instance - is created. This way you can for example register classes (django does it and uses it for example to create tables in the database). Since `class` is an instruction you can think about as a decorator for a class.